# Spring Boot: io.FileNotFound Exception when returning a file not cought by try - catch block

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I want to return a Zip file from the server.
For files that are present it works as expected, the file gets returned ans all is fine.
My issue is for files that do not exist.
Here I want to return an 404-Error, but currently a 500 is returned because the
"java.io.FileNotFoundException : URL [...] cannot be resolved in the file system for checking its content length" Exepction is not cought in the controller.

Here is my code for the controller:

```
@GetMapping("analysis/daily/{year}/{month}/{day}/{mode}")
public ResponseEntity<Resource> getDailyAnalysis(
@PathVariable("year") int year, 
@PathVariable("month") int month,
@PathVariable("day") int day, 
@PathVariable("mode") AnalysisSelection type) {
    try {
        Resource resource;
        Path fileBasePath = Path.of("Analysis", "ZIP", "Daily",
                String.valueOf(year),
                String.valueOf(month),
                String.valueOf(day));
        switch (type) {
            case ByItem -> {
                fileBasePath = fileBasePath.resolve("SingleItemAnalysis.zip");
            }
            case ByAuthor -> {
                fileBasePath = fileBasePath.resolve("Author.zip");
            }
            case ByType -> {
                fileBasePath = fileBasePath.resolve("Type.zip");
            }
            case ByIndustry -> {
                fileBasePath = fileBasePath.resolve("Industry.zip");
            }
            default -> {
                throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            }
        }
        resource = new UrlResource(fileBasePath.toUri());
        return ResponseEntity.ok().contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/zip"))
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + resource.getFilename() + "\"")
                .body(resource);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();
        throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

}
```

Weirdly, the stack trace points towards the Spring Security JWT-Token implementation:
specifically this line: "filterChain.doFilter(request, response);"

```
@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String jwt = getJwtFromRequest(request);

    if (StringUtils.hasText(jwt) && jwtTokenProvider.validateToken(jwt)) {
        String mail = jwtTokenProvider.getUserMailFromToken(jwt);
        UserDetails userDetails = appUserDetailedService.loadUserByUsername(mail);
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());

        authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
    }

    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

Here is the entire Stack Trace:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: URL [file:/C:/Users/walter/Documents/digitales2go/backend/Analysis/ZIP/Daily/2023/7/18/Author.zip] cannot be resolved in the file system for checking its content length

        at org.springframework.core.io.AbstractFileResolvingResource.contentLength(AbstractFileResolvingResource.java:240)                                                                             

        at org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter.getContentLength(ResourceHttpMessageConverter.java:121)

        at org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter.getContentLength(ResourceHttpMessageConverter.java:45)

        at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.addDefaultHeaders(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:260)

        at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:211)

        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:293)

        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:219)

        at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:78)

        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:135)

        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)

        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)

        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)

        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067)

        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)

        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)

        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)

        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)

        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)

        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)

        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)

        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:111)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)

        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327)

        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)

        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81)

        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)

        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122)

        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116)

        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)

        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126)

        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81)

        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)

        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:109)

        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)

        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149)

        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)

       at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)

        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)

        at de.myProject.security.jwt.JwtAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtAuthenticationFilter.java:40)

        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)

        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)

        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103)

        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89)

        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)

        at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91)

        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)

        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)

        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)

        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)

        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)

        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)

        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110)

        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80)

        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)

        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55)

        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)

        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)

        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211)

        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183)

        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354)

        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)

        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)

        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)

        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)

        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)

        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)

        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)

        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)

        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890)

        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1743)

        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)

        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)

        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)

        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)

        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Any ideas on how  to make sure the proper HTTP error is returned?

See code above for details

Comment: All your web requests go through your filter chain. It's normal behaviour.

Comment: @Jorn but how do I make sure that the 404 Error code is returned then? None of my other Controllers (JSON ones) behave that way, that an error cannot be caught by a try-catch block and a selected HTTP Status be returned.

Comment: Either catch the exception in your endpoint (controller) code and return it there, or register an ExceptionHandler to catch the exception and transform it to the response you want.

Comment: I am attempting to catch the exception in the end point.... that's what the entire question is about.... But having the ENTIRE end point code in a try-catch block does not catch it. This is the issue I have written the question for.

Comment: You obviously have to catch the exception from where it's thrown. The stacktrace should tell you that, and I don't see any `de.myProject` code on top of it. So, it's not actually thrown from inside your endpoint.

Comment: de.myProject is the entire Project, of 15k+ LOC.As written in the question, the Stack Trace points towards the security filter "filterChain.doFilter(request, response);", not the controller.  The second code snippet is the exact method the Stack Trace points to, it is part of the de.myProject package, as is the first code snipped showing the controller being used.  The controller, which is trying to access the non-existing file, is in a try-catch block, so should not throw the error. It is the only part where the file is attempted to be opened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add

```
...        
    default -> {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }
    if (!Files.exists(path)) {
      throw new FileNotFoundException()
    }
    resource = new UrlResource(fileBasePath.toUri());
 ...
```

`